# GnuCash: Paying for others - direct or indirect transfers?

Tags: gnucash

Suppose I am going to a restaurant with 5 friends. Suppose we are in the US because then we have to pay together. Suppose I take the bill of 500$ with my credit card. I receive the money of one friend via Venmo (100$), of one via PayPal (100$); one friend pays me cash (100$) and I pay for myself and my girlfriend (200$).

Now I could enter the transaction on my credit card account `Liabilities:Credit Cards:Visa` using the following splits:

```
Friend 1      Assets:Venmo                   100
Friend 2      Assets:PayPal                  100
Friend 3      Assets:Cash:Wallet             100
Girlfriend    Expenses:Gifts                 100
Myself        Expenses:Dining                100
              Liabilities:Credit Cards:Visa       500
```

An alternative way would be to have an intermediate account (or intermediate accounts) `Assets:Lent:Friend 1`, etc or `Assets:Lent:Friends` and the splits look like:

```
Friend 1      Assets:Lent:Friends            100
Friend 2      Assets:Lent:Friends            100
Friend 3      Assets:Lent:Friends            100
Girlfriend    Expenses:Gifts                 100
Myself        Expenses:Dining                100
              Liabilities:Credit Cards:Visa       500
```

Then, I separately make bookings from my Venmo & PayPal accounts, but also from my cash account. The individual transactions within `Assets:Lent:Friends` would look like:

```
Got money back from Friend 1   Assets:Venmo                   100
Got money back from Friend 2   Assets:PayPal                  100
Got money back from Friend 3   Assets:Cash:Wallet             100
```

Which of the two ways is the more preferred one? (I know both work)

Comment: I would only bother with the more complex option 2 if there was a long delay between paying the bill and being reimbursed. Is it really of interest in the long run that you covered your friends temporarily?

Comment: I always prefer your alternative way.

Comment: Is this really only a matter of taste? Any pros and cons for each way?

Comment: The benefit to option 2 is that your records match the time frame of the actual transactions, and would simplify reconciliation.  My primary comment on your example is that what we're talking about here is implicitly a loan (no matter how willingly you made that loan).  Thus using accounts based in the Asset category is incorrect- it should be something like Liabilities:Loan to Friends.

Comment: Hmm, I think only if I take a loan, right? If I borrow something it goes into `Liabilities:Borrowed from Friends`. But if I loan something it is actually an asset (or a pre-payment). I think I asked that long time ago on the gc mailinglist and got told to put that into `Assets:Lent to Friends` and `Liabilities:Borrowed from Friends` ...

Answer (score 1):

It's essentially like you've invoiced your friends for the food bill. I would credit the credit card for the full transaction, debiting your portion to *Expenses:Food* or similar, and debiting the amounts owed by your friends to *Assets:Accounts Receivable*. When they cover their debt to you, then you will credit Accounts Receivable and debit whichever of your accounts they sent the money to. Doing this with a split transaction will make reconciliation nicer, because then your credit card statement will match the GnuCash entries, but whether you use a split transaction or not is your choice.

Here's what such a split transaction would look like when entered into your credit card ledger:

```
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+---------------+
| Date        | Description/Memo   | Account                    | Payment/Debit | Charge/Credit |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+---------------+
| 18 Sep 2020 | Fancy Restaurant   |                            |               |               |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+---------------+
              | Credit card charge | Liabilities:Credit Card    |               |        500.00 |
              +--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+---------------+
              | My owing           | Expenses:Food              |        200.00 |               |
              +--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+---------------+
              | Alice's owing      | Assets:Accounts Receivable |        100.00 |               |
              +--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+---------------+
              | Bob's owing        | Assets:Accounts Receivable |        100.00 |               |
              +--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+---------------+
              | Charlie's owing    | Assets:Accounts Receivable |        100.00 |               |
              +--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Accounts Receivable will then show one item for each split that is associated with it:

```
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| Date        | Customer           | Transfer                   | Invoice/Debit | Payment/Credit |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
|             | Memo               |                                                             |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| 18 Sep 2020 | Fancy Restaurant   | -- Split Transaction --    |        100.00 |                |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
|             | Alice's owing      |                            |               |                |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| 18 Sep 2020 | Fancy Restaurant   | -- Split Transaction --    |        100.00 |                |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
|             | Bob's owing        |                            |               |                |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
| 18 Sep 2020 | Fancy Restaurant   | -- Split Transaction --    |        100.00 |                |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
|             | Charlie's owing    |                            |               |                |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

If you were charging interest on your friends' debt, *then* I might class it as an asset, e.g. under *Assets:Loans Receivable*, since it will yield income. Alternatively, you can just use Accounts Receivable for this purpose, in the same manner that a business might charge statutory interest on an overdue bill for services.